# updating data in firestore database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to update data from firestore database.
It looks like,
[image: firestore database]

There is my try to update the data

```
// Update a post value
  const updatePost = async (postId) => {
    console.log('Update Post Id: ', postId);
    await firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection(`${user.email}`)
      .doc(postId)
      .update({
        value: value,
        todos: todos,
      })
      .then(()=> {
        setTodos([]);
        setValue('');
        setEditModalVisible(!editModalVisible)
      })
      .catch(error => console.log('Error updating post.', error))
  }
```

If I provide a static postId it updates properly, however, If I provide a dynamic postId like the above snippet, it only updates the last post, If I try to update the first or second post, It **always updates the last post**,

Here is my code snippet for UI

```
<FlatList
    data={post}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
      <View
        <View
         
        >
        <View>
            <Modal
            animationType="slide"
            transparent={true}
            visible={editModalVisible}
            >
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => updatePost(item.id)}
            >
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </Modal>
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
    </View>
 />
```

Comment: what is postid ? the document id or field in firestore?

Comment: It is document id